# Error compiling fragment shader in react native with tensorflowJs

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I made a class whose objective is to predict the type of plant along with its disease, both models have the same structure and the first prediction on the type of plant I have no problems, the error that I still do not know what is due is when I do the predict of the second model (the disease of the plant).

```
import { bundleResourceIO } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as ImageManipulator from "expo-image-manipulator";
import { decodeJpeg } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import { ModelsEnfermedades } from "../utils/routesModels";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

class PlantDiseaseClassifier {
  constructor() {
    this.plantModel = null;
    this.modelEnfermedad = null;
    this.classNames = [
      "Apple",
      "Cherry",
      "Corn",
      "Grape",
      "Peach",
      "Pepper",
      "Potato",
      "Strawberry",
      "Tomato",
    ];
    this.enfermedades = [
      {
        Apple: ["scab", "blackrot", "cedar apple rust"],
        Cherry: ["Powdery Mildew"],
        Corn: [
          "Cercospora Leaf Spot Gray Leaf Spot",
          "Common Rust",
          "Northern Leaf Blight",
        ],
        Grape: ["Black Rot", "Black Measles", "Isariopsis Leaf Spot"],
        Peach: ["Bacterial spot"],
        Pepper: ["Bacterial spot"],
        Potato: ["Early Blight", "Late Blight"],
        Strawberry: ["leaf scorch"],
        Tomato: [
          "Bacterial spot",
          "Early blight",
          "Late blight",
          "Leaf Mold",
          "Septoria leaf spot",
          "Two-spotted spider mite",
          "Target Spot",
          "Mosaic virus",
          "Yellow Leaf Curl Virus",
        ],
      },
    ];
  }

  async loadPlantModel() {
    const modelJson = require("../context/model_ia/model_bueno.json");
    const modelWeights = require("../context/model_ia/archivo_bueno.bin");
    /* const modelJson = require("../context/model_ia/Modelos_Enfermedades/PROBANDO.json");
    const modelWeights = require("../context/model_ia/Modelos_Enfermedades/Apple.bin"); */

    try {
      await tf.ready();
      this.plantModel = await tf.loadGraphModel(
        bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights)
      );
      console.log("Modelo de plantas cargado");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error en cargar el modelo de plantas", error);
    }
  }

  async loadDiseaseModel(predictedClass) {
    console.log("Predicted Class:", predictedClass);

    const diseaseModelJson = ModelsEnfermedades[predictedClass].json;
    const diseaseModelWeights = ModelsEnfermedades[predictedClass].bin;

    try {
      if (!diseaseModelJson || !diseaseModelWeights) {
        throw new Error(`Model files not found for ${predictedClass}`);
      }

      await tf.ready();
      this.modelEnfermedad = await tf.loadGraphModel(
        bundleResourceIO(diseaseModelJson, diseaseModelWeights)
      );

      console.log(`modelo de enfermedades de  ${predictedClass} cargado`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        `error en cargar el modelo de enfermedades de ${predictedClass}`,
        error
      );
    }
  }

  async resizePhoto(uri, size) {
    const actions = [{ resize: { width: size[0], height: size[1] } }];
    const saveOptions = {
      base64: true,
      format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.JPEG,
    };
    const result = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      uri,
      actions,
      saveOptions
    );
    return result.uri;
  }

  async processImage(image, setPrediction) {
    try {
      if (!this.plantModel) {
        console.error("Model not loaded desde processImage");
        return;
      }

      const resizedUri = await this.resizePhoto(image, [128, 128]);

      const imgB64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(resizedUri, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      });

      const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, "base64").buffer;
      const raw = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer);
      const imgTensor = decodeJpeg(raw);
      /* const imgTensor = tf.tensor3d(raw, [128, 128, 3], "float32").div(255.0); */
      const normalizedTensor = imgTensor.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255));

      const processedTensor = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
        normalizedTensor,
        [128, 128]
      );
      const expandedTensor = tf.expandDims(processedTensor, 0);
      console.log(expandedTensor);
      const prediction = await this.plantModel.predict(expandedTensor);
      const resultArray = await prediction.array();

      const predictedClassIndex = tf.argMax(resultArray[0]).dataSync()[0];
      const predictedClass = this.classNames[predictedClassIndex];
      /* const predictedClass = this.enfermedades[0].Apple[predictedClassIndex]; */
      const confidence = resultArray[0][predictedClassIndex];
      setPrediction(predictedClass);

      console.log(
        `la clase predicha es ${predictedClass}, con una confianza de ${confidence}`
      );

      // Carga y predicción del modelo de enfermedad correspondiente

      await this.loadDiseaseModel(predictedClass);
      console.log(expandedTensor);

      // Predicción de la enfermedad
      const diseasePrediction = await this.modelEnfermedad.predict(
        expandedTensor
      );
      console.log(diseasePrediction);
      const diseaseResultArray = await diseasePrediction.array();
      console.log(diseaseResultArray);

      tf.dispose([
        imgTensor,
        normalizedTensor,
        processedTensor,
        expandedTensor,
        prediction,
      ]);

      /* setTimeout(() => {
        navigation.navigate("Plant");
      }, 3000); */
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error en la prediccion:", error);
    }
  }
}

export default PlantDiseaseClassifier;
```

what I get on console is

```
Modelo de plantas cargado
 LOG  {"dataId": {"id": 118}, "dtype": "float32", "id": 118, "isDisposedInternal": false, "kept": false, "rankType": "4", "scopeId": 5, "shape": [1, 128, 128, 3], "size": 49152, "strides": [49152, 384, 3]}
 LOG  la clase predicha es Apple, con una confianza de 0.96142578125
 LOG  Predicted Class: Apple
 LOG  modelo de enfermedades de  Apple cargado
 LOG  {"dataId": {"id": 118}, "dtype": "float32", "id": 118, "isDisposedInternal": false, "kept": false, "rankType": "4", "scopeId": 5, "shape": [1, 128, 128, 3], "size": 49152, "strides": [49152, 384, 3]}
 LOG  1    #version 300 es
2        precision highp float;
3        precision highp int;
4        precision highp sampler2D;
5        in vec2 resultUV;
6        out vec4 outputColor;
7        const vec2 halfCR = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
8
9        struct ivec5
10       {
11         int x;
12         int y;
13         int z;
14         int w;
15         int u;
16       };
17
18       struct ivec6
19       {
20         int x;
21         int y;
22         int z;
23         int w;
24         int u;
25         int v;
26       };
27
28       uniform float NAN;
29
30
31
32         #define round(value) newRound(value)
33         int newRound(float value) {
34           return int(floor(value + 0.5));
35         }
36
37         ivec4 newRound(vec4 value) {
38           return ivec4(floor(value + vec4(0.5)));
39         }
40
41
42       int imod(int x, int y) {
43         return x - y * (x / y);
44       }
45
46       int idiv(int a, int b, float sign) {
47         int res = a / b;
48         int mod = imod(a, b);
49         if (sign < 0. && mod != 0) {
50           res -= 1;
51         }
52         return res;
53       }
54
55       //Based on the work of Dave Hoskins
56       //https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4djSRW
57       #define HASHSCALE1 443.8975
58       float random(float seed){
59         vec2 p = resultUV * seed;
60         vec3 p3  = fract(vec3(p.xyx) * HASHSCALE1);
61         p3 += dot(p3, p3.yzx + 19.19);
62         return fract((p3.x + p3.y) * p3.z);
63       }
64
65
66   vec2 uvFromFlat(int texNumR, int texNumC, int index) {
67     int texR = index / texNumC;
68     int texC = index - texR * texNumC;
69     return (vec2(texC, texR) + halfCR) / vec2(texNumC, texNumR);
70   }
71   vec2 packedUVfrom1D(int texNumR, int texNumC, int index) {
72     int texelIndex = index / 2;
73     int texR = texelIndex / texNumC;
74     int texC = texelIndex - texR * texNumC;
75     return (vec2(texC, texR) + halfCR) / vec2(texNumC, texNumR);
76   }
77
78
79   vec2 packedUVfrom2D(int texelsInLogicalRow, int texNumR,
80     int texNumC, int row, int col) {
81     int texelIndex = (row / 2) * texelsInLogicalRow + (col / 2);
82     int texR = texelIndex / texNumC;
83     int texC = texelIndex - texR * texNumC;
84     return (vec2(texC, texR) + halfCR) / vec2(texNumC, texNumR);
85   }
86
87
88   vec2 packedUVfrom3D(int texNumR, int texNumC,
89       int texelsInBatch, int texelsInLogicalRow, int b,
90       int row, int col) {
91     int index = b * texelsInBatch + (row / 2) * texelsInLogicalRow + (col / 2);
92     int texR = index / texNumC;
93     int texC = index - texR * texNumC;
94     return (vec2(texC, texR) + halfCR) / vec2(texNumC, texNumR);
95   }
96
97
98     float getChannel(vec4 frag, vec2 innerDims) {
99       vec2 modCoord = mod(innerDims, 2.);
100      return modCoord.x == 0. ?
101        (modCoord.y == 0. ? frag.r : frag.g) :
102        (modCoord.y == 0. ? frag.b : frag.a);
103    }
104    float getChannel(vec4 frag, int dim) {
105      float modCoord = mod(float(dim), 2.);
106      return modCoord == 0. ? frag.r : frag.g;
107    }
108
109
110      float sampleTexture(sampler2D textureSampler, vec2 uv) {
111        return texture(textureSampler, uv).r;
112      }
113
114
115      void setOutput(vec4 val) {
116        outputColor = val;
117      }
118
119  uniform sampler2D x;
120  uniform int offsetx;
121  uniform float value;
122
123      ivec4 getOutputCoords() {
124        ivec2 resTexRC = ivec2(resultUV.yx *
125                               vec2(NaN, NaN));
126        int index = resTexRC.x * NaN + resTexRC.y;
127
128
129        int b2 = index / -6.82298071533994e+24;
130        index -= b2 * -6.82298071533994e+24;
131
132
 LOG  ERROR: 0:133: '' : syntax error: ERROR___INTEGER_CONST_OVERFLOW
 LOG   133        int b = index / 62340447705453330;
 LOG  134        index -= b * 62340447705453330;
135
136        int r = 2 * (index / -55721349);
137        int c = imod(index, -55721349) * 2;
138
139        return ivec4(b2, b, r, c);
140      }
141
142
143      vec4 getX(int b2, int b, int row, int col) {
144        int index = b2 * 98304 + b * 1536 + (row / 2) * 48 + (col / 2);
145        int texR = index / 48;
146        int texC = index - texR * 48;
147        vec2 uv = (vec2(texC, texR) + halfCR) / vec2(48, 2048);
148        return texture(x, uv);
149      }
150
151      vec4 getXAtOutCoords() {
152        ivec4 coords = getOutputCoords();
153        coords.x = 0;
154        vec4 outputValue = getX(coords.x, coords.y, coords.z, coords.w);
155        return outputValue;
156      }
157
158
159        const ivec4 start = ivec4(1031726203,1015076891,-1115744482,-1143684921);
160        const ivec4 end = ivec4(1031726204,1015076955,-1115744418,-1143684825);
161
162        void main() {
163          ivec4 outputLoc = getOutputCoords();
164          vec4 result = vec4(0.);
165
166          ivec4 rc = outputLoc;
167          if (any(lessThan(rc, start)) || any(greaterThanEqual(rc, end))) {
168            result[0] = float(value);
169          } else {
170            ivec4 source = rc - start;
171            result[0] = getChannel(getX(source.x,source.y,source.z,source.w), vec2(source.z,source.w));
172          }
173
174          rc.w += 1;
175         if(rc.w < -111442699) {
176
177          if (any(lessThan(rc, start)) || any(greaterThanEqual(rc, end))) {
178            result[1] = float(value);
179          } else {
180            ivec4 source = rc - start;
181            result[1] = getChannel(getX(source.x,source.y,source.z,source.w), vec2(source.z,source.w));
182          }
183
184          }
185         rc = outputLoc;
186         rc.z += 1;
187         if(rc.z < -2237578552) {
188          if (any(lessThan(rc, start)) || any(greaterThanEqual(rc, end))) {
189            result[2] = float(value);
190          } else {
191            ivec4 source = rc - start;
192            result[2] = getChannel(getX(source.x,source.y,source.z,source.w), vec2(source.z,source.w));
193          }
194
195            rc.w += 1;
196           if(rc.w < -111442699) {
197          if (any(lessThan(rc, start)) || any(greaterThanEqual(rc, end))) {
198            result[3] = float(value);
199          } else {
200            ivec4 source = rc - start;
201            result[3] = getChannel(getX(source.x,source.y,source.z,source.w), vec2(source.z,source.w));
202          }
203        }}
204          setOutput(result);
205        }
206
 ERROR  Error en la prediccion: [Error: Failed to compile fragment shader.]
```